# How to run only specific lines of code from a file?

Tags: python

I was wondering how can I run only a small part of the code without running all the previous ones, such a thing would be very handy to me because I'm writing code just to see how it works and I do that in the same Python file, so when I want to run just the one I recently wrote it also runs all the previous ones.

I only want to run the highlighted part, not all the previous lines:

[image]

Comment: Try putting your individual code snippets in separate functions and call the specific one that you want, rather than executing all of the code as a script.

Comment: If this code were written properly, each piece would be its own function.  (I see Kai beat me to that.)  In the short term, you can comment out all the other lines (using '#') and run what's left.

Comment: Either use functions, separate files, or work in an interactive console... You can also just temporarily comment code you don't want to run. Seeing you're using Pycharm this can be easily done by highlighting code and pressing `ctrl+/` (and again to un-comment)

Comment: The ctrl+/ command isn't working for me, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Look in the `edit` menu at the top. There should be a command `comment with line comment`

Answer (score 1):

you should make all your codes inside functions.
and call it inside the main function.
for example:

```
# Import necessary libraries.

# Define your functions from the top
def Foo():
    print('foo')

def Bar():
    print('bar')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Run your code from here, call the needed functions.
    Foo()
    Bar()
    # If you don't want to run Bar(), simply comment it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitions/ Functions are the best way to go for this.

```
def afunc():
    print('This is the function printed after the other function')


def func():  # Starts the definition

    print('This is a function')
    

    afunc()

func() # Runs the Code
```

Comment: This is just the most basic thing you can do. You can also have definitions run other definitions. This is one of the most important parts of python.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Pycharm specifically, but I know in many other IDEs for python (VS Code, Spyder, Jupyter), you can break out the script into cells and run each cell individually.

For VS Code and Spyder, you desginate different cells by including lines that start with `#%%`

This will also open up an interactive python shell where you can modify and re-run each section or type out individual lines to run